# Conditional Expectation, product of random variables

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

I struggle with showing the following.

Let $\tau$ be an exponentially distributed random variable, that means $\mathbb P(\tau > x)=\mathrm{exp}(-x)$ and $\xi$ a bounded random variable.

Show that $$\mathbb E\left[\xi\frac{\mathbb 1_{(x<\tau\leq y)}}{\tau}\right]=0\quad \text{for all $x,y$ with $0<x<y$}$$
implies 
$$\mathbb E\left[\xi\mid\tau\right]=0.$$

Maybe you can help me with that.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true for any positive random variable $\tau$. Exponential distribution is note required. $E(\xi |\tau)=0$ iff $E(\frac {\xi} {\tau} |\tau)=0$ iff $E(\frac {\xi} {\tau} I_A)=0$ for any set $A$ of the type $\{\tau \in E\}$ where $E$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$. It is enough
 to prove this when $E$ is an open interval and in this case what we need is exactly the hypothesis.

PS: there is no guarantee that $\frac {\xi} {\tau}$ is integrable. To avoid this problem we can replace $\xi$ by $\xi I_{\{\tau >\epsilon\}}$ in the proof and let $\epsilon\to 0$ at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Isn't it necessary for $E(\xi\mid\tau)=0\iff E\left(\frac\xi\tau\mid\tau\right)=0$ to hold that we have $E\left|\frac\xi\tau\right|<\infty$ which does not have to be the case here.

Comment: @AgnethaTimara You are right  but that can easily be circumvented. It is enough to to show that $E( \xi I_{\tau >\epsilon}|\tau)=0$ for each $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying that. Can you also tell me why it suffices to show that for a generating set of the $\sigma$ algebra $\sigma(\tau)$. Is there a theorem I can refer to or can I use dominated convergence?

Comment: @AgnethaTimara The $\pi -\lambda$ Theorem or Dynkin's Theorem is ideally suited for this kind of situation. It tells you immediately why it is enough to consider intervals.

Comment: Sorry for the many questions. I really appreciate your help.

These theorems tell me that the intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$ algebra.
I don't understand yet why $\int_{\{x<\tau\leq y\}} Z=0$ implies $\int_{\{\tau\in E\}} Z=0$ for $E\in \mathcal B$ and $Z$ a random variable.
Obviously $E$ can be represented as a union / intersection of intervals but for example $\int_A Z=0$ for $A\in\{A_1,\ldots A_n\}$ does not imply $\int_{\bigcup_i A_i}Z=0$

Comment: @AgnethaTimara You cannot prove this from definitions. Are you familiar with $\pi- \lambda$ theorem? Billingsle'y book has a proof of this theorem. Alternatively, you can use the fact that finite unions of half closed intervals form an algebra which generates the Borel sigma algebra, so Monotone Convergence Theorem can be used.